# No Concurrency despite SessionStateBehaviour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session, httphandler, orchardcms

In our application a page is served which subsequently is supposed to make a bunch of asynchronous calls for more data in parallel.  These calls were being queued and I read that calls using the same session are queued because of complications that can arise from having more than one request write to the same session.

I also read that a controller can be set to `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` or `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` if sessionless or we do not need to write to the session.

I have tried these as I don't need to write to the session so I figured the requests would be served concurrently, or if I was using the session without realizing it, an exception would be thrown.

Neither of these is the case.  Requests from a same user are still being queued.

How can I verify that my directive `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` is being respected?
What could be causing this problem?

In case it is relevant, we are working within the context of [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/).

Comment: For testing purposes disable the session completely and see if it works: `<sessionState mode="Off" />` in your web.config.

Comment: But some requests to other controllers do require the session... but maybe I can give that a try somehow.

Comment: Give it a try. You will see how much better is without sessions :-) Your application will be RESTFul and stateless, the way all web applications should be designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the underlying HTTP handler that's being used for every Orchard route request is implementing `IRequiresSessionState` interface. It's the reason every request is actually queued...

It's a known issue and we'll be trying to fix that in the next Orchard version, as long as it won't imply a breaking change. There are couple of core features (and unknown number of external, custom ones) that rely (or may rely) on Session, so simple removal of the `IRequiresSessionState` interface is not an option. We need to refactor things first and implement some opt-in/opt-out mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In Orchard 1.6 you can set `SessionState` property of a `RouteDescriptor` to`SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` or `SessionStateBehavior.Disabled`.

So all you need to do is to create a new route in your `Routes` class that maps to your controller and has one of the above `SessionStateBehaviors`. You don't need to decorate the controller with `SessionState` attribute afterwards.